# Sparse matrix multiplication with NA

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

Performing matrix multiplication on sparse matrices in R gives a different result as the same operation performed on dense forms of the same matrices *if* there are `NA`'s in the data.

Some data to demonstrate on:

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(123)
m1  <- Matrix(data=sample(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,NA),25, T), ncol = 5, nrow = 5, sparse = F)
m2  <- Matrix(data=sample(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,2,NA),25, T), ncol = 5, nrow = 5, sparse = F)
sm1 <- Matrix(m1, sparse = T)
sm2 <- Matrix(m2, sparse = T)
```

Now if we do

```
m1 %*% m2

# 5 x 5 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    2   NA    0    0    2
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

we get a different result to

```
sm1 %*% sm2

# 5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                  
# [1,]  . NA  . . NA
# [2,]  2 NA  . .  2
# [3,]  . NA NA .  2
# [4,] NA NA  . . NA
# [5,] NA NA  . .  2
```

The cause of this seems to be that while `0 * NA` returns `NA`,  a zero (or missing location) in a sparse matrix returns zero when multiplied by NA.

We can see this behaviour in

```
0 %*% NA
     [,1]
[1,]   NA

Matrix(data=0, sparse=T) %*% NA
1 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1]
[1,]    0
```

Is there any way to get sparse matrix multiplication to always yield the same result as dense matrix multiplication when there can be NA's in the data (other than, of course, converting to their dense forms, which defeats the object of using sparse matrices in the first place)?

**Update**

Comments suggest that different people are seeing a variety of different behaviours.   I have tested on 64-bit Linux (kubuntu 16.04), R 3.2.3, Matrix 1.2-3, **and** on R 3.3.1, Matrix 1.2-6.

The following all give the same result for me:

```
m1 %*% m2
as.matrix(m1) %*% as.matrix(m2)
as.matrix(sm1) %*% as.matrix(sm2)
```

Whereas

```
sm1 %*% sm2
```

gives different value, as shown above. Similar discrepancies are seen when matrices contain `Inf` or `NaN`.

-

However, slightly different behaviour was seen by @user20650, who reports in the comments that they also see varying results on Ubuntu 14.04 (x32), Matrix v1.2-6, R v3.3.1, but in different combinations to me. In their case,`m1 %*% m2`, and `sm1 %*% sm2` both give same answer as i had for `sm1 %*% sm2`. But, `as.matrix(m1) %*% as.matrix(m2)` and `as.matrix(sm1) %*% as.matrix(sm2)` both give the result that I get for `m1 %*% m2`.

Comment: The result I get from `m1 %*% m2` differs from yours.  Are you sure you copied the right matrix?

Comment: ditto ^^. I cant reproduce this... both give the same output

Comment: @RichardScriven I just copied and pasted this code into a fresh R session, and got the same result.  I'll paste the contents of m1 and m2 into the question too, to double check we have the same matrices.

Comment: Either way, the question still holds because I *do* get `0` for `Matrix(data=0, sparse=T) %*% NA`

Comment: also get different results for `as.matrix(m1) %*% as.matrix(m2) ` abd
 `m1 %*% m2`

Comment: @user20650 I see the identical results for `as.matrix(m1) %*% as.matrix(m2)`,   `m1 %*% m2`, and `as.matrix(sm1) %*% as.matrix(sm2)`  . Only `sm1 %*% sm2` gives different result. Perhaps there are platform or version dependent differences? I've added additional information on version/platform to the question in case this is part of the issue.

Comment: @dww; my results: I get the same results for both
 `m1 %*% m2`, and `sm1 %*% sm2` (which you get for `sm1 %*% sm2`). 
Using either `as.matrix(m1) %*% as.matrix(m2)` or
`as.matrix(sm1) %*% as.matrix(sm2)` , I get 
the result thst you get for `m1 %*% m2`.
Ubuntu 14.04 (x32), Matrix v1.2-6, R v3.3.1

Comment: would this be worth raising on `r-devel@r-project.org` and/or pinging Martin Mächler (`maintainer("Matrix")`) ? related: https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/slowing-down-matrix-multiplication-in-r/